# C# Get accessor is inaccessible

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, enumerable

I have the following class definition:

```
 public static string SplitString(string someText)
 {
      var queryArray = Regex.Split(someText, "\\s+(?=\\w+)");
      foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, queryArray.Count - 1)) {
           // Some code
      }
 }
```

The problem is that queryArray.Count is giving me the following error:

The property 'System.Array.Count' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessable.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Arrays have a `Length` property, not a `Count`, as far as I know.

Comment: Instead of `var` define `queryArray` as `string[]` and the IDE will help you with this :)  {That you should be using `Length` on an array instead of `Count`}

Comment: As mentioned, there is no `Count` property on an array. What I'll add is that if you ever see `Count` being called on an array, it's likely that it's a method (so, it's `myArray.Count()` < notice the brackets), and that the `System.Linq` namespace has been added, because that contains the extension method of `Count()`.

Comment: I still don't get why he is getting this error. When I try to reproduce, I get a `Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'int'.`. I don't know the using used but since `Enumerable` is used without namespace, I would guess there is a `using System.Linq;` somewhere, which when used generates an other error.

Comment: @Paciv Perhaps it is the mono compiler, or an older version of csc.exe.  The error suggests that the `.Count` member is resolving to the explicit implementation of `ICollection<T>.Count`, but I can't reproduce the error with csc.exe (VS 2012), either.  I don't have mono handy to check it out there.

Comment: Maybe you're right because I wasn't getting the usual 'Cannot resolve symbol' error but the one I mentioned which got me thinking that Count property does exist but I'm somehow using it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) property instead:

```
public static string SplitString(string someText)
{
    var queryArray = Regex.Split(someText, "\\s+(?=\\w+)");
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, queryArray.Length - 1)) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Also your code would probably have been more readable if it was written like this:

```
public static string SplitString(string someText)
{
    var queryArray = Regex.Split(someText, "\\s+(?=\\w+)");
    for (var i = 0; i < queryArray.Length; i++) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
public static string SplitString(string someText)
{
    var queryArray = Regex.Split(someText, "\\s+(?=\\w+)");
    foreach (var item in queryArray) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Now I feel dumb for asking... The issue was that I wasn't getting the standard 'Cannot resolve symbol' error which would indicate that Count method does not exist for Arrays so that had me confused.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Split` returns an array, which doesn't define a `Count` property. Use `Length` instead:

```
 public static string SplitString(string someText)
 {
      var queryArray = Regex.Split(someText, "\\s+(?=\\w+)");
      foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, queryArray.Length - 1)) {
           // Some code
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Length property`

Answer (score 0):

Why worry about an index when the Select extension will get it for you:

```
var data = Regex.Split("someText other", "\\s+(?=\\w+)")
                .Select((itm, indexer) => string.Format("{0} is index {1}", itm, indexer));

/* Data has 2 strings in the list:

someText is index 0
other is index 1

*/
```